# How to get child mount to trigger first in vue-router async loading components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using vue/vue-router to load a website. This is the code that demonstrates the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.6/vue-router.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
        <script>
            Vue.component('a-a', function(resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    resolve({
                        template : "<div>A</div>",
                        mounted : function() {
                            alert(1);
                        }
                    });
                }, 2000);
            });
            new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                router : new VueRouter({
                    mode: 'history',
                    routes: [
                        { path: '/foo', component: Vue.component("a-a") }
                    ]
                }),
                mounted : function() {
                    alert(2);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I modified IIS to allow REST style links to return the above page like this

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SPA Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <!-- match everything by default -->
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <!-- unless its a file -->
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <!-- or a directory -->
        <!--<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />-->
        <!-- or is under the /api directory -->
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
        <!-- list other routes or route prefixes here if you need to handle them server side -->
      </conditions>
      <!-- rewrite it to /index.html -->
      <action type="Rewrite" url="App/test2.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

When I visit the page, I use the link `/App/test2.html/foo`, and it returns the page above.

What I then expect is vue-router to load the component based on the url path, then async load the component, waiting on the resolve function, then run the mounted function on the child, then finally run the mounted function on the parent. So basically alert 1, then 2. But the parent alerts first, so it does 2, then 1.

How can I get the child to mount first?

Thanks

Comment: How would you expect the child to mount if there's no parent in which to mount it?

Comment: Child mounting before parent is standard behavior though.

Comment: "Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted."

[Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)

Comment: Would a next tick in the parent mounted work?

Comment: I think nexttick within the mounted function may work, or window.onload

Comment: it didn't work. I think it doesn't wait for the 2 second timeout